# Invoke batch job from EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, batch-processing

I am trying to invoke the batch job from EJB. My batch job is based on javax.batch-api-1.0.jar, not spring. In my ejb, I use following lines to invoke the batch job:

```
JobOperator jobOperator = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();
Properties props = new Properties();
long execID=jobOperator.start("myBatch-job", props);
```

However, it failed. Debug shows that the BatchRuntime.getJobOperator() returns null. Could anyone tell me why the invocation failed? Thanks.

=====
The problem should be that I failed to inject JobOperator to EJB. But I don't know how to fix it. I tried using @Inject,

```
@Inject
JobOperator jobOperator;

...

Properties props = new Properties();
jobOperator.start("myBatch-job", props);
```

and I also add a JobProducer class:

```
@Named
public class JobProducers {

    @Produces
    @Default
    public JobOperator getJobOperator() {
        return BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();
    }
}
```

However, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which server did you try? You need an Java EE 7 application server.

Comment: Can you post the whole imports ? And as well the implementation of the JobOperator ? Thanks